# Android User tracking application which prevent it self from being killed by users

Tags: android, root

I am working on an Android enterprise application that targets limited mobile devices which help owner to track the user/device status (like GPS, Calls logs) remotely. I managed to implement these basics features to my application. Challenge that I'm facing now is the end users who traveling away with the device can force stop the application or can revoke some permissions(above Marshmallow) to prevent them self from being tracked remotely by the owner.

> First of all is it possible to make such an application?
>
> If yes, what are APIs given for such applications  development?

Note - All the targeted devices are **rooted** anything I can get advantage of that.

> Is there are any special APIs available for developments of those applications which work only on Rooted devices?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement i will suggest you to look deep into the android [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

As You might also have a look on the persistent service,
You can only make your service persistent if you are developing system apps. This service is basically unkillable.

Here is some write up for [persistent service](http://devescape.blogspot.in/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html)

Hopefully this might help you.

But for non-system applications, startForeground is your best option.

Comment: Since we got Root access, is there any possibility to make this app as system application? Because this is not going to play store anyway. Planing to integrated while ship the devices.

Comment: It is basically done that the app is digitally signed by the manufacturer otherwise the application wont  run.

But http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1776095 this thread might be helpful for you.